# Downloading a file with python through the REST API at myfxbook.com

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, rest

I am trying to download the economic calendar from https://www.myfxbook.com/forex-economic-calendar using python. I can do this manually but would like to automate it. I have tried curl as well but seem to be missing something. I have also tried with downloading the data in xml format but couldn't get that to work either.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigestAuth

url = 'https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&end=2022-07-13%2022:59:59.059&start=2022-07-11%2023:00:00.0&calPeriod=10&tabType=0'
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, allow_redirects=True, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'))

print(response)
print(response.content)
print(response.text)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers['content-type'])
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to both what you tried & what problem(s) you had?

Comment: If I click the the link to download it in CSV or XML format it works. The XML is displayed in the browser in a new tab. The CSV is downloaded to disk. Sometimes it has valid data and sometimes it's empty. I believe this has to do the the format of time. Sometimes an '&' is specified instead of space between the date and time and this causes an issue. I have never been successful in downloading the data via python. I believe you have to use your credentials to download the data as well. The website gives free access so anyone can setup an account and test what I am referring to.

Comment: I am not sure on the correct terminology here but I believe the REST API redirects the output data somehow and I am not handling this correctly. The website doesn't offer any documentation on how to use python to download the file. Since I can do it manually with a couple clicks I am assuming there should be a way to automate this with python but I haven't discovered it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```py
import requests
URL = "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&end=2022-07-13%2022:59:59.059&start=2022-07-11%2023:00:00.0&calPeriod=10&tabType=0"
response = requests.get(URL)
open("calendar_statement.csv", "wb").write(response.content)
```

Comment: Hello, this doesn't download the data. Did you test it, the file is empty?

Comment: @mholm_bc When i download your file is empty to. Mybe try an other url ?

Comment: I tried both of these in your python code but the file was still empty. If I paste these into Chrome I see the results as expected.

Comment: URL = "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.csv?filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&end=2022-07-13%2022:59:59.059&start=2022-07-11%2023:00:00.0&calPeriod=10&tabType=0"
    URL = "https://www.myfxbook.com/calendar_statement.xml?filter=0-1-2-3_AUD-CAD-CHF-CNY-EUR-GBP-JPY-NZD-USD&end=&start=&calPeriod=10&tabType=0"